# Can I make a shortcut to Send Outlook Email from Template?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-client, templates

Using the information provided [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-an-email-message-template-HA101829163.aspx), I was able to successfully create an email template and send a message using this template.

However, using this template is quite cumbersome - one must go to `New Items->More Items->Choose Form...->`*Change "Look In" path to User Templates In File System*`->Open`.

It's almost faster to just "Forward" a sent email and delete the extraneous forwarding metadata. Can anyone please tell me how to speed this up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For email templates I use a lot, I simply place a shortcut on your desktop linked to the template. All you need to do is go find your template in Windows Explorer, right click on it and choose `Sent to > Desktop (create shortcut)`

As it is stated in the article, here are the paths to the templates locations (unless you saved your template elsewhere);

> Windows 7 and Windows Vista
>   c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\microsoft\templates
>
> Windows XP
>  c:\documents and settings\username\application
>   data\microsoft\templates

Then all you have to do is use the shortcut to open your template in one step.

Comment: Well, like I said above, I prefer having a button to appear on the bar because it just feels more natural, but your way is much, much better - Especially perfect for multiple templates. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you found this useful. Sorry, I don't see anything about a "button" in your question.

Answer (score 5):

I found some info about doing this with a macro, and it works in 2013, but I don't have 2010 to test it on.

If you don't have macros enabled, you will need to go into the Trust Center and enable all macros, which Outlook advises against doing because malicious code could run. Then you have to add a custom group to the ribbon and add macros to that custom group.  Then you can get down to making the macro for a new message from a .oft template file. (more MSDN instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx))

The macro code will look like this:

```
Sub TemplateName()
    Set msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\template.oft")
    msg.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: Office 2012? Did you mean 2013? 2011?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, 2013. Fat-finger.

Comment: This is great - I love having "in-app" methods to do things - feels less like it's a "hack". I'll try this out and let you know how it goes in O2010!

Comment: If you don't like the idea of enabling all macros or always having a confirmation dialog pop up before running: 1) Set your macro policy to notify for signed macros and disabling other macros 2) Self-sign your macro (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/digitally-sign-your-macro-project-956e9cc8-bbf6-4365-8bfa-98505ecd1c01) 3) Restart Outlook and run the macro once, trusting the certificate

Answer (score 2):

If you find the template file in your filesystem (see CharlieRB's answer), then you can drag it to your Taskbar and add it to the Outlook quick menu, so it appears when you right-click. That way it appears next to the New Email and New Meeting shortcuts.

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen. Two clicks. Done. Amazing this isn't supported directly in the product

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to "CharlieRB". You can further make it faster by adding a Global shortcut key as follows.

Add a Global Shortcut key to the item on the desktop as shown in the screenshot.  Right click on the Desktop item-> Properties

[image: Outlook Shortcut key to compose email from template]

Comment: It looks like you were the person who submitted the anonymous edit to add this to CharlieRB's answer.  You really should pick one route or the other to avoid duplication.  Since this is actually a different solution, I'll roll back the edit on the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and didn't like any of the answers, so after a bit of experimenting, this is my solution:

1. save the e-mail template into templates; take a note where this template folder is (you can simply right click on the dir and select "copy" and later paste that path into Windows "Exploder").
2. in my Outlook mail account, create a subfolder called "templates" (or whatever you want to call it)
3. in Windows "Exploder" go to the filesystem folder where I saved the template as a file - this is why you needed to take a note where it was
4. drag this e-mail template file into the templates folder in my Outlook
5. whenever I want to use that template, just click on the template in the templates folder in my Outlook maildirs, or in my case in Favorites since I've added the templates maildir folder in my Favorites.

NOTE: I haven't tested this against the "new" Outlook (new in 2023, the one which is probably called Outlook 365, or whatnot, which can't even open EML or PST files - I've tried that bad upgrade and went quickly back to "old" Outlook). There's a chance this may not work there either (since it's crap - the New Outlook that is).

You're welcome :-).