# How to create an email template when default email handler doesnot support file template?

Tags: email

How to set up a template so that when I double click it, an email handler opens with the preset addresses, Header and Body?

if Outlook is installed, [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/606914/can-i-make-a-shortcut-to-send-outlook-email-from-template) gives a solution. But what if the default email handler does not support a template file, say **Mail** of windows 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

save the following in an .html file:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
window.onload = window.location.href = "mailto:MAILADDR1,MAILADDR2...?subject=ABC&body=XYZ";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

replace `MAILADDR1, MAILADDR2 ...` with the desired preset email addresses separating them with a comma, `ABC` with desired subject/header, `XYZ` with desired body.

double clicking the .html will open the default browser, and automatically default email handler will open with the preset addresses, header and body